# Wordpress: Could not create directory

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress, mkdir

When trying to upload new plugins to wordpress, i am always faced with the same "Could not create directory." error.

From debugging i have determined the directory thats failing to be created is `/wp-content/upgrade/new-shop.1.0.6-10/new-shop/template-parts`.

As a good test, i have run `chmod 777` on wp-content, as well as set `chown www-data:www-data`.

`drwxrwxrwx   8 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3 14:20 wp-content`

Subsequent child directories are also set to these permissions

`drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3 14:10 upgrade`

Further to this, updating installed plugins fails:

"Update Failed: Could not create directory."

/wp-content/upgrade/akismet.4.1.4-QrVWAO/akismet/views

I don't know how else to make the wp-content directory any more open or accessible ( let alone unsafe ).

I'm using Wordpress 4.9.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Update:
Some progress has been made with updating plugins by enabling `write_enable=YES` for vsftpd, however still getting issues on uploading plugins

src: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/wp-upgrade-cant-create-directory-even-though-perms-are-777

Comment: Is SELINUX enabled?

Comment: @NasirRiley SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: maybe you can try chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content

Answer (score 0):

I believe i solved this by enabling the FTP server, vsftpd in my case.

enable `write_enable=YES` for vsftpd.conf config.

After removing all data inside `wp-content/uploads` & `wp-content/upgrades`, this now appears to be working.

[src:] https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/wp-upgrade-cant-create-directory-even-though-perms-are-777